# Trouble with AJAX PHP upload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am creating an AJAX PHP upload script, but I am having troubles. After the user selects an image to upload, it will show in the div container that I specified in the javascript file (good). But, the moving the uploaded file does not seem to work, or at least I think that is what the problem is. I set the uploads/ folder to have permission of "777".

Here is the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#upload-image-button").hide();

  var input = document.getElementById("images"),
    formdata = false;

  function showUploadedItem(source) {
    var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
        li = document.createElement("li"),
        img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = source;
    $("#topic-img-container").html(img);
  }  

  if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
    $("#upload-image-button").hide();
  }

  $("input[type='file']").live("change", function(event) {
    $("#response").html("Uploading...");
    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
      file = this.files[i];

      if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        if (window.FileReader) {
          reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        if (formdata) {
          formdata.append("images[]", file);
        }
      }
    }

    if (formdata) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "db/upload_image.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (res) {
          document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
        }
      });
    }
  }, false);
});
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
  foreach($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      print_r($_FILES);
      $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
      move_uploaded_file($FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
      echo $FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    }
  }

  echo "Success";
?>
```

It gets into the loop when there is no error. When I go to the upload folder, there are no new files. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Never assume the move call succeeded. `if (!move_uploaded_file(...)) { die("Move failed"); }`. As well, NEVER use the user-provided filename for your filesystem operations. Your construct lets a malicious user scribble their file ANYWHERE on your server. Consider a filename of `../../../../../etc/passwd` and what your code will try to do with that.

Comment: @Marc B I would hope the server and hence PHP is running as a user that wouldn't have permissions to edit files like that.

Comment: While I agree with that in principle Endo, you generally want to make your code as idiot-proof and hack-proof as possible.  Never assume another level of security will handle it if you can handle it at this level!  Especially since security securing the passwd file might not secure index.html, or some other random but important file.

Comment: @endophage: defensive programming starts with never assuming your operational environment is "secure".

Comment: @Marc B I'm well aware of that.  I'm not saying you shouldn't have other protections, but making sure your server user is well locked down should always be step 1 in setting up a production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. You need a helper Iframe that you send via a regular form-post.

Comment: Not true with HTML5, check out the HTML5 rocks site.